# Global Vars in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, global

I want to save some global vars to use in the website, like current user id, current user lever, and so on. Where is the best place to do it, or is it possible?

Setting it into constants.php is not working since "$this" is not recognized there.

The principal reason why I want this is because i don't like using sessions (I consider writing strings like `$this->session->userdata('session_name')` not so practical, writing something like CURR_UID is more easy to do it and read as well)

Comment: Yeah totally. Globals everywhere is always better. The simplicity of it all is so much more practical than normal object oriented principles that have been battle-tested for years and years and agreed upon as best practices by the brightest minds in the field. -***sigh***-

Comment: The data that you want to handle IS session data. So, even though you don't like sessions, that would be the best way to deal with this data.

Comment: Sessions are not even comparable to global variables. You're comparing apples and oranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but it isn't the way that Codeigniter was designed. Sessions are really the place for this kind of thing (namely, stuff that persists from one page view to the next), but you could [wrap the session calls up in a library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) for beauty's sake if you wanted. Something like this:

```
// in libraries/User.php
class User {

  protected $ci;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->ci = &get_instance();
  }

  public function id() {
    return $this->ci->session->userdata('user_id');
  }

  // etc, etc.
}
```

Once you've written a few more helpers like `id()`, you can use them to access the relevant variables elsewhere in your application:

```
$this->load->library('user');
echo 'Current user ID is: ' . $this->user->id();
```

Comment: Thanks @rjz so after all, i can't just define it, i have to use classes and funtions...too bad but still better then $this->ci->session->userdata('user_id');

Comment: You *can* define it, but (as you can probably guess from the comments above) these kind of things usually end in disaster :-)

Comment: in the function id(), return is missing :) thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do in this case is create a `class My_Controller extends CI_Controller`. Sort out all the functionality that you would need before actually loading any of the specific controller functionality.

Then any subsequent class you create you can do: `class Whatever extends My_Controller`.

Edit: I forgot to mention you should put the `My_Controller` class within the Application > Core folder.